# Don't display the overlay with the Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I was wondering if it's possible to remove the automatic overlay made by the recently implemented Navigation Drawer ? (The grey layer on the second picture)

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You just need to set `setScrimColor(int color)` to your `DrawerLayout` :

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.WHITE);
// OR
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Here is the official documentation from Android API: [DrawerLayout - setScrimColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setScrimColor%28int%29).

Hope this solves your problem! : )