# Android - Change tint background color to navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm working with Navigation Drawer and i need to change the color of tint background from black to green.
any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This :

```
yourDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need update latest support library.

latest version- 25.4.0

Add this repository in,

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Project level build.gradle

Update your xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"//Change background color
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"//Set your header
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"//Change Text color
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />// set your menu items.
```

Comment: isn't what i asked.
check the attached picture.
what you say is to change to drawer background, not the tint color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129598/dont-display-the-overlay-with-the-android-navigation-drawer , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745300/navigation-drawer-semi-transparent-over-status-bar-not-working  try this.